# Android 12 - Bluetooth permission automatically denied

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions, android-12

I am struggling with the new Android 12 Bluetooth permissions. For some reason my Bluetooth permissions are automatically being denied and I am getting this warning message:

`Can request only one set of permissions at a time`

Here is my code:

```
public void requestBluetooth() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            beforeBluetoothGranted = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);

            if (beforeBluetoothGranted) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Warning")
                        .setMessage("App must grant Bluetooth permissions in order for BiSym to operate!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
            }
        }
    } else {
        requestBluetoothScan();
    }
}

public void requestBluetoothScan() {
    //does the same as requestBluetooth for the scan permissions
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        ...
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestBluetoothScan();
                } else {
                    afterBluetoothGranted = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                }
                if (!(beforeBluetoothGranted || afterBluetoothGranted)) {
                    gotoSettings();
                }
            }
        break;
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (!mApp.trialShown) {
                        openWhatsNewDialog();
                    }
                } else {
                    afterBluetoothGranted = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                }
                if (!(beforeBluetoothScanGranted || afterBluetoothScanGranted)) {
                    gotoSettings();
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Bluetooth is critical to the functionality of our app. I am new to the Android 12 Bluetooth permissions and this does not seem right that the permissions would automatically be denied.

Comment: Why not request both scan and connect permissions together? They will be requested as Near By devices group permission AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

missing in manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

in MainActivity

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);
        }
```

bad english sorry :)